# R Data Table - join but filter with update

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to figure out how to join 2 data tables and update the first but with a filter applied.

```
DT<-data.table(a=rep(1:3,3),b=seq(1:9))
DT
   a b
1: 1 1
2: 2 2
3: 3 3
4: 1 4
5: 2 5
6: 3 6
7: 1 7
8: 2 8
9: 3 9

DT2 <- data.table(b=seq(1:9), c=rep(10,9))
> DT2
b  c
1: 1 10
2: 2 10
3: 3 10
4: 4 10
5: 5 10
6: 6 10
7: 7 10
8: 8 10
9: 9 10
```

I can do a basic equijoin like so

```
DT[DT2, on=c(b="b")]
```

But what I'd like to do logically is this

```
DT[a==3,DT2, on=c(b="b")]
```

but I get the following error

```
Error in `[.data.table`(DT, a == 3, DT2, on = c(b = "b")) : 
  logical error. i is not a data.table, but 'on' argument is provided.
```

I can reverse the order of the join and apply the filter...

```
DT2[DT[a==3,], on=c(b="b")]

   b a
1: 3 3
2: 6 3
3: 9 3
```

Which gives the correct rows but the column order is incorrect.  That aside I'd like to update DT with c but only for the rows I've filtered in DT and that satisfy the join.

If this was SQL I would use an update with a subquery like so:

```
UPDATE
    DT
set
    c = (select c from DT2 where DT2.b = DT.B)
WHERE
    DT.a=3
```

I seem to be going in circles with the Data table syntax - can anyone point me in the right direction?

Cheers

David

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a `dummy` variable `a` in `DT2`, join on both columns *a* and *b* and then *Update*:

```
DT[DT2[, c(a = 3, .SD)], c := i.c, on = c("a", "b")]

DT
#   a b  c
#1: 1 1 NA
#2: 2 2 NA
#3: 3 3 10
#4: 1 4 NA
#5: 2 5 NA
#6: 3 6 10
#7: 1 7 NA
#8: 2 8 NA
#9: 3 9 10
```

Comment: nice!  Thank you.  I'll mark the question as answered as soon as the time limit expires and I can click the button!

Comment: `DT[.(a = 3, DT2), c := i.c, on = c('a', 'b')]` would be more concise - not sure why you went the `.SD` route

Answer (score 5):

Another option without having to make a dummy variable is:

```
DT[a==3, c := DT2[DT[a==3], c, on = c(b="b")]]
DT
#   a b  c
#1: 1 1 NA
#2: 2 2 NA
#3: 3 3 10
#4: 1 4 NA
#5: 2 5 NA
#6: 3 6 10
#7: 1 7 NA
#8: 2 8 NA
#9: 3 9 10
```